# Program not going through method

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program based on these parameters:

Create a program called RandomArray that will generate an array called numArray of 10 random
integer numbers greater than 1 and less than or equal to 100. The program should ask the user to enter
an integer greater than 0 and less than 100. The program should then display all of the numbers in the
array that are larger than the number the user entered.

You will need a random number generator called ranNumber and use it to populate the integer array
called numArray with 10 numbers greater than 0 and less than or equal to 100. Ask the user to enter a
number called userNum greater than 0 and less than 100. Create a static void method called
displayGreaterThan that uses the enhanced for loop to step through the array and an if statement to
compare the array contents to the number the user entered. The method should display the numbers
from the array that are greater than the number the user entered.

The problem is that when I run my program I don't get ten results back with my random number generator.  It's differs with each number entered and I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
public class RandomArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SecureRandom ranNumber = new SecureRandom();
        int NumArray[] = new int[10];

        int userNum;
        int choice;
        int num = 0;

        {
            num = 1+ ranNumber.nextInt(100);
            displayGreaterThan (num);
        }

    }//end of main

    public static void displayGreaterThan(int num)
    {
        int userNum ;
        int numArray[] = new int[10];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number 1 to 100");
        userNum = input.nextInt();
        while ( userNum < 1 || userNum > 100)
        {
            System.out.println("error please try again.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a number 1 to 100");
            userNum = input.nextInt();
        }

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= numArray.length; counter++)
        {
            SecureRandom ranNumber = new SecureRandom();
            num = 1+ ranNumber.nextInt(100);
            if (num > userNum)
            {   numArray[1]++;
                System.out.println( + userNum + " is your random number");
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong because this shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend breaking it up a bit more just to make each procedure more simple. You declared the scanner twice, once in the main, which isn't necessary. The `displayGreaterThan` procedure has a lot going on, which I think is what is causing you some issues. Not that this is perfect, but it's something you could compare with what you have to simplify what you are trying to do.

```
public class RandomArray 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        int[] intNumArray = new int[11];
        int intUserNumber = 0;

        // Get random numbers
        intNumArray = GenerateRandomNumbers();

        // Get user initial user input
        intUserNumber = GetUserInput(intUserNumber);

        // Validate and recursively call procedure if invalid
        if(intUserNumber < 1 || intUserNumber > 100)
        {
            // Get user input again if invalid
            intUserNumber = GetUserInput(intUserNumber);
        }

        // Display results
        DisplayGreaterThan(intUserNumber, intNumArray);

        // Print array for double checking
        PrintArray(intNumArray);

    }

    public static int[] GenerateRandomNumbers()
    {

        SecureRandom ranNumber = new SecureRandom();
        int[] intNumArray = new int[11];

        for(int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 11; intCounter++)
        {
            intNumArray[intCounter] = ranNumber.nextInt(100);

        }     
        return intNumArray;
    }

    public static int GetUserInput(int intUserNumber)
    {
        Scanner clsScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
        intUserNumber = clsScanner.nextInt();

        return intUserNumber;

    }

    public static void DisplayGreaterThan(int intUserNumber, int[] intNumArray)
    {
        System.out.println("The array values greater than " + intUserNumber + ":");

        for(int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 11; intCounter++)
        {
            if(intNumArray[intCounter] > intUserNumber)
            {
                System.out.println("#" + intCounter + " = " + intNumArray[intCounter]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[] intNumArray)
    {
        System.out.println("The random array values:");

        for(int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 11; intCounter++)
        {
            System.out.println("#" + intCounter + " = " + intNumArray[intCounter]);
        }
    }
}
```